# No visible @interface for 'AFHTTPSessionManager' declares the selector 'GET:parameters:progress:success:failure:'

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I am getting this error after the installing of pod AFNetworking 4.0.1
,Below is the code:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)GET:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(id)param progress:(NECBProgress)progress success:(NECBSucess)success failure:(NECBFailure)failure {
    return [self.manager GET:URLString parameters:param progress:^(NSProgress *downloadProgress) {
        if(progress) progress(@(1.0 * downloadProgress.completedUnitCount / downloadProgress.totalUnitCount));
    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id data) {
        @try {
            LoggerI(@"GET-URLString:%@",URLString);
            LoggerI(@"GET-Reponse:%@",[data jsonStringEncoded]);
            if (success) success(task,data);
        } @catch (NSException *exception) {
            LoggerE(@"数据异常 HTTP：%@",URLString)
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        LoggerI(@"GET-URLString:%@",URLString);
        LoggerI(@"GET-Error:%@",error.localizedDescription);
        if (failure) failure(task,error);
    }];
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)GET:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(nullable id)parameters headers:(nullable NSDictionary <NSString *, NSString *> *)headers progress:(nullable void (^)(NSProgress * _Nonnull))downloadProgress success:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull, id _Nullable))success failure:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable, NSError * _Nonnull))failure` without passing `headers`. This is how you can fix it:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)GET:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(id)param progress:(NECBProgress)progress success:(NECBSucess)success failure:(NECBFailure)failure {
    return [self.manager GET:URLString parameters:param headers:nil progress:^(NSProgress *downloadProgress) {
        if(progress) progress(@(1.0 * downloadProgress.completedUnitCount / downloadProgress.totalUnitCount));
    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id data) {
        @try {
            LoggerI(@"GET-URLString:%@",URLString);
            LoggerI(@"GET-Reponse:%@",[data jsonStringEncoded]);
            if (success) success(task,data);
        } @catch (NSException *exception) {
            LoggerE(@"数据异常 HTTP：%@",URLString)
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        LoggerI(@"GET-URLString:%@",URLString);
        LoggerI(@"GET-Error:%@",error.localizedDescription);
        if (failure) failure(task,error);
    }];
    
}
```

Comment: Hey you are Super . It worked for me , Thanks a-lot.

Comment: But Now my header text is missing .What to do?

Comment: @Rasmita Try to use another value for `headers`, not `nil`. Or what header do you mean?